# Arithmetically simulate 32-bit integer overflow

Tags: type-conversion, wolframalpha

Is there a way to arithmetically simulate 32-bit, twos-complement integer overflow with numbers of a type whose value space is a strict superset of that of the 32-bit twos-complement integers?  I need to perform such an operation in, for example, WolframAlpha, which has no explicit typing and no type casting.

The output of my desired `convertTo32BitSignedInt(aValue)` function needs to be the same as if I had cast the value in a language that supports it, such as Java: `(int)aValue`.

By example, the output of `convertTo32BitSignedInt(17643225600`) needs to be `463356416`, the same as I had used the following cast `(int)17643225600`.

For the moment, my `convertTo32BitSignedInt` function (in pseudo code) looks like this and I am pretty sure it's not the better solution.

```
if(x > 2147483647 && floor(x / 2147483647 ) == 1){
    return (x - 2*2147483648);
}else if(x > 2147483647 && (x % 2147483647 == 0) && (x % 2 == 0)){
    return -1 * (x / 2147483647);
}else if(x > 2147483647 && (x % 2147483647 == 0) && (x % 2 > 0)){
    return -1 * ((x - 2147483647) / 2147483647) + 2147483647;
}else if(x > 2147483647 && (x % 2147483647 > 0) && (x % 2 == 0)){
    return  -1 * floor(x / 2147483647) + (x % 2147483647);
}
//...
```

**Use Case:**

I try to demonstrate a certain behavior that will occures when there is a 32-bit signed integer overflow in a java program  using a recursive implementation of the factorial function.

```
public int factorial(int n) {
    return n == 1 || n==0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

This `int` implementation, for `factorial(13)` gives `1932053504`, because `13 * 479001600 > 2147483647`, the 32-bit signed integer maximum value.

I use WolframAlpha for the demonstration. WolframAlpha allows numbers > 2147483647 and I want to simulate these number as 32-bit integer numbers. WolframAlpha gives the real answer which is `6227020800`. I would like to be able to convert `6227020800` as `1932053504.`

Comment: Well it's not my downvote, but it's very unclear... especially as your final sentence seems to contradict your earlier statement of "In fact, I want that convertTo32BitSignedInt(aValue) == (int)aValue in every case."

Comment: (int)17643225600 equals 463356416 and convertTo32BitSignedInt(17643225600) needs to output 463356416

Comment: Now it should be clear and the last line has been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: this is a rip & replace of my initial answer*

You can do something roughly like this:

```
convertTo32BitSignedInt(aValue) {
    bits32 = BitAnd(aValue, BitShiftLeft(1, 32) - 1);
    sign = BitShiftRight(bits32, 31);

    return bits32 - BitShiftLeft(sign, 32);
}
```

Comment: Then your question does not make sense.  If WolframAlpha has no (explicit) data types, then in particular, it has no `double` and no "32-bit signed int".

Comment: Also, it's not really anything to do with Java if you're not looking for a solution written in Java.

Comment: I know, I want to simulate it (a signed 32 bit integer) I would not talk about double. WolframAlpha allows numbers > 2147483647 and I want to simulate these numbers as If it was int

Comment: Revised my answer to reflect the question being asked.